# How can I compare a list with every row in a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list like v=[1,1,1] and a dataframe like [[1,1,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,0]].
I want to compare this list to dataframe rows if any row equal to my list print somthing and stop comparing. how can i do this?

Comment: you can use pyinstaller this https://www.pyinstaller.org/

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:

Step 1: Install pyinstaller

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Step 2:

Put all the three python file in a Folder.(same)

Open Command Promt in that folder and write:

```
pyinstaller.exe 1.py --onefile --noconsole
```

*noconsole is optional as it is used to run python file without popping command prompt window.

General Syntax:

```
pyinstaller.exe filename.py --onefile --noconsole
```

Thanks

Comment: I did but this error:pyinstaller.exe : The term 'pyinstaller.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pyinstaller.exe erafc.py --onefile --noconsole
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pyinstaller.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: you installed pyinstaller? Right? If you did..Then...

locate to: pyinstaller 
general location: C:/Python27/Scripts/pyinstaller.exe

if u manage to locate pyinstaller, then Copy Path.

and then write in cmd:

C:/Python27/Scripts/pyinstaller.exe 1.py --onefile --noconsole

I'm sure it will solve your error. If it's solved. Then Do Upvote The Answer. Thanks.